# Flutter / How to insert url into an image using a carousel package

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel, url-launcher

Hello im beginner in Flutter and I'm studying carousel package.
I really need your advisement.
Is there any way to call different url links if I press each of sliding images?

here is my code with carouselSlider:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:1/size_config.dart';

class know extends StatefulWidget {
  const know({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<know> createState() => _know();
}

class _know extends State<know> {
  int _current = 0;
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  List imageList = ['assets/images/1.png', 'assets/images/2.png'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 150,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [sliderWidget(), sliderIndicator()],
      ),
    ));
    /* onTap: () {
          launchUrl(Uri.parse(
              'httplink'));
        }); */
  }

 Widget sliderWidget() {
    return CarouselSlider(
      carouselController: _controller,
      items: imageList.map(
        (imgLink) {
          return Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Image(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: AssetImage(
                    imgLink,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 300,
        viewportFraction: 1.0, 
        autoPlay: true, 
        autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget sliderIndicator() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: imageList.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => _controller.animateToPage(entry.key),
            child: Container(
              width: 12,
              height: 12,
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 4.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color:
                    Colors.white.withOpacity(_current == entry.key ? 0.9 : 0.4),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've looked up a lot of references, but I haven't figured out how to apply the link separately using url_launcher.

Answer (score -1):

Are the url links point to pages inside your app or they are external to your app?
Anyway, i have done something similar to this, and on the builder, i wraped it a InkWell.
Each slider knows its index, so,if you have an object as value on the map, you can access those url dynamically, or you can do your own logic on the onTap method.

Comment: in your case, i mean wrap the SizedBox.

Comment: They are external, I wanted to point an article on internet. Originally i used onTap method to link url in one image. and If possible, I would like to continue using this method. Is it better to make a list with url as well as image?

Comment: in my opinion, yes, its easier that way, since then you will have a List of an object, and you can then access the property of the url and de img.
And since it already knows the index, you dont even have to do something like Obj[index].url or Obj[index].image. you just need the Obj.url or Obj.image

Comment: Thanks, as you said, I made a list of links. but may I ask one more question? The error 'Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uri'' occurs when I run the app. I wrote 'onTap: _launchUrl(urlList)' inside SizedBox which is wrapped, and defined _launchUrl seperatly. I'm really sorry to interrupt, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: you are trying to launch the list itself. I guess you just did a List with all the url's that you needed.
you need to access the list to get each url, and not the list itself

Comment: You cannot ask for help with one line question. This is the sign of laziness. That to me is the title. Then should follow a detailed explanation of what you are doing, what you want to achieve and what is happening. You can include where necessary snippets of your codes.